# I cant figure out how to SetValue using reflections

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

i have been trying to use reflections for some time now and sadly my efforts lead me to errors, what i am trying to do is get the field of a integer from another script and change it, here is my code:

My first script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameInformation : MonoBehaviour 
{

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }

    //1 is bought while 0 is not bought
    public static int TipJar;
}
```

My Second Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System;


public class Upgrades : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameInformation gio;

    void Start()
    {
        gio = GameObject.Find("lol").GetComponent<GameInformation>();

        Type myClassType = gio.GetType().GetField("TipJar").SetValue(gio, 1, null); //<-- Error
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Sorry for asking a nooby question i am still learning how to program and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd really recommend against using static and/or public fields.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I am doing this inside a forloop and i don't want to write the reference one by one, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the overloaded variant of [`GetField(string name, BindingFlags flags)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
gio.GetType().GetField("TipJar", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(null, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

TcKs answer should work for you, I just as addition would like to point that you don't need an instance of `GameInformation`. You can use something like:

```
typeof(GameInformation).GetField("TipJar", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(null, 1);
```

So basically you don't need to find instance reference of `GameInformation` to get static field.

Comment: @JeryySwitalski ah did not know that, thanks a bunch.